# Is it possible to "Reload everything except" using pjax?

Tags: javascript, pjax

Is it possible using pjax to do something like "Reload everything in body except footer and header"?

I've tried `<a href="/home" data-pjax="body:not(footer):not(header)">go</a>` But it is not working (footer and header disappears).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the suggestive way of using a PJAX Call

When you wanted to refresh a division, you must provide a valid identifier.
Header and Footer elements are part of body, there is nothing called **leaving out** for header and footer.

Alternatively, define a **#id** to your division to refresh

```
  <body>
       <header>

       </header>
       <div id="pjax-container">

       </div>
       <footer>

       </footer>
  </body>
```

Now provide a link like

```
  <a href="/home" data-pjax="#pjax-container">
```

I believe this could be found over the PJAX Documentation.

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to use it with HTML 5 bloilerplate template. This template put the javascript links after the footer. So if a page have a specific javascript. I'm forced to place the javascript after the footer (as jquery and other are loaded after the footer). So if I try to load a page with specific Js. The js won't be loaded... But if it's not possible I'll find an other way.

Comment: @RobinCarlier I have used PJAX before, I believe there is no neccessary/condition that the javascripts should be placed below the footer. Please kindly provide the url of the HTML5 BoilerPlate Template you are using.

Comment: I'm using [this](https://github.com/mattsnider/django-html5-boilerplate), As you see the problem is that to use this template. I have to put the js files in pre_main_script and post_main_script blocks. Thos blocks are placed below the footer. jsut before body ends. Indeed nothing force me to place customs js here. except that Jquery is loaded here. So I have to re load jquery or have to not use it. Wich is a problem.

Comment: @RobinCarlier Does pre_main_script appear after the footer?? Can't you place the pre_main_script inside the **{% block head %}**

Comment: It does indeed. Every js file appears after. There is an option to put them in the <head>, I'll try it to see if i can't place scripts in the pjax containter then.

Comment: would you mind posting how the page source looks after this is generated?

Comment: It looks like [this](http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?34c996e9d5803ead#cffS5s60AfAfrNB6+tOvOcG0sLY2ohQ1wWsj/aXp0Lo=)

Comment: Nvm, I found the option place scripts in head. I accept this answer as it tell me wether it was possible or not.

Comment: Does this pre_main_script and/or post_main_script does give any kind of minification/bundling when moving to production? If does not have a purpose in production, please remove and give them over the **{% block head %}** as normal HTML Tags.

Comment: Apart from being that, you could also try placing the **{% block pre_main_script %}** in **{% block head %}**